# Liquidsoap - Use PulseAudio With Static Image

Tags: icecast, liquidsoap

I am using liquidsoap to stream audio from my murmur server, as well as a static image, to icecast. However, I can't seem to get liquidsoap to use my JPEG file

```
Failed to register plugin /usr/lib/frei0r-1/facebl0r.so: Frei0r.Not_a_plugin
Failed to register plugin /usr/lib/frei0r-1/facedetect.so: Frei0r.Not_a_plugin
Invalid value at line 6, char 14-43:
  Could not get a valid media file of kind {audio=0;video=1;midi=0} from "/home/iandun/stream/test.jpg".
```

The file does exist, and I used GIMP to create it. My code (quites short), is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/liquidsoap

set("frame.video.width", 800)
set("frame.video.height", 600)

video_file = "/home/iandun/stream/test.jpg"

video = single(video_file)

source = mux_video(video=video,input.pulseaudio(device = "stream.monitor"))

output.icecast(%ogg(%vorbis,%theora),     host = "duncan.usr.sh", port = 8000,      
password = "my_password", mount = "test.ogv",     
source,fallible=true)
```

What am I doing wrong?